# jquery insertAfter element with data-list?

Tags: jquery

I normally insert my table rows using code similar to :

```
$('#' + id).insertAfter('#LS\\:' + arr[1]);
```

`id` is unique and is the row I'm inserting, `#LS: + arr[1]` is what I'm inserting before and is the ID of the row. eg: `#LS:666`

Due to the layout of the table I'm working on I can't use the rows ID, but I can use it's data attribute `data-list`

So my question is how do I change my `insertAfter` to work with data-list ?
The rows data list will contain the following format :  `LS:666`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('[data-list="' + valueHere + '"]').insertAfter('#LS\\:' + arr[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's where it's inserting after that has the data-list value, not the row that is being moved.

Comment: OK - This seems to  work: `$('#' + id).insertAfter('[data-list="LS\\:' + arr[1] + '"]');`

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood where you needed to use the attribute selector, but it's the correct technique at least